# Github pages automatic page generation doesn't generate html

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages

I made special repository to store documentation. I wanted to use Github automatic pages generation option (not Jekyll).

It is said, that as soon as you push to gh-pages branch, html will be generated. But it's not. Why?

https://github.com/evdokp/testdocs

You can see there test.md file, and not test.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking into the wrong site.
When you create a GitHub page it'll be hosted in `https://<your-user>.github.io/<project>`. So, in your case, the proper link to see the page is in: https://evdokp.github.io/testdocs/